# Failed to resolve import, but the path is valid, and detected as such by VSCode

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Here is my code: https://github.com/d0uble-happiness/DiscogsCsvVue

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <FileUpload @file="setFile" />
    <ParseCsvToArray v-if="file" :file="file" />
    <ProcessReleaseData />
    <FetchRelease />
    <DownloadCSV />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import FileUpload from './components/FileUpload.vue';
import ParseCsvToArray from './components/ParseCsvToArray.vue';
import ProcessReleaseData from './components/ProcessReleaseData';
import FetchRelease from './components/FetchRelease';
import DownloadCSV from './components/DownloadCSV';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    FileUpload,
    ParseCsvToArray,
    ProcessReleaseData,
    FetchRelease,
    DownloadCSV
  },
  data() {
    return {
      file: null as null | File,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setFile(file: File) {
      console.log("Received file:", file)
      this.file = file;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("mounted");
  },
});
</script>

<style></style>
```

processReleaseData.vue

```
import { type GetReleaseResponse } from '@lionralfs/discogs-client/types/types';

export default  {
  name: 'ProcessReleaseData',
  methods: {
    processReleaseData
  }
}

export function processReleaseData(releaseId: string, data: GetReleaseResponse) {

  const { country = 'Unknown', genres = [], styles = [], year = 'Unknown' } = data;
  const artists = data.artists?.map?.(artist => artist.name);
  const barcode = data.identifiers.filter(id => id.type === 'Barcode').map(barcode => barcode.value);
  const catno = data.labels.map(catno => catno.catno);
  const uniqueCatno = [...new Set(catno)];
  const descriptions = data.formats.map(descriptions => descriptions.descriptions);
  const format = data.formats.map(format => format.name);
  const labels = data.labels.map(label => label.name);
  const uniqueLabels = [...new Set(labels)];
  const qty = data.formats.map(format => format.qty);
  const tracklist = data.tracklist.map(track => track.title);
  // const delimiter = document.getElementById('delimiter').value || '|';
  const delimiter = '|';
  const formattedBarcode = barcode.join(delimiter);
  const formattedCatNo = uniqueCatno.join(delimiter);
  const formattedGenres = genres.join(delimiter);
  const formattedLabels = uniqueLabels.join(delimiter);
  const formattedStyles = styles.join(delimiter);
  const formattedTracklist = tracklist.join(delimiter);
  const preformattedDescriptions = descriptions.toString().replace('"', '""').replace(/,/g, ', ');
  const formattedDescriptions = '"' + preformattedDescriptions + '"';
  const formattedData: any[] = [
    releaseId,
    artists,
    format,
    qty,
    formattedDescriptions,
    formattedLabels,
    formattedCatNo,
    country,
    year,
    formattedGenres,
    formattedStyles,
    formattedBarcode,
    formattedTracklist
  ];

  return formattedData;
}
```

But for some reason I'm getting this error when I try to run my app:

> Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "@lionralfs/discogs-client/types/types" from "src/components/ProcessReleaseData.ts". Does the file exist?

I checked tsconfig.app.json, and it looks fine to me:

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue", "csv.ts", "src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Module "d:/MY DOCUMENTS/CODE/DISCOGS API CLIENT/DiscogsCsvVue/node_modules/@lionralfs/discogs-client/types/types" appears to be valid and is showing up just fine in VsCode. I copied the location from the VSCode pop-up so I don't see any issue there. `import { DiscogsClient } from '@lionralfs/discogs-client';` is working just fine in another file in the same directory.

Any tips please? TIA

Comment: There's no /types/types.ts which is expected when you omit an extension. It's /types/types.d.ts based on this https://unpkg.com/browse/@lionralfs/discogs-client@4.0.0/ .' And .d.ts aren't expected to be directly imported. Any useful types are supposed to be exported from package entry point, which is probably not the case for GetReleaseResponse . Otherwise a safer way is to infer them from public types, e.g. with ReturnType, because internal types can become unavailable with any breaking change. If this is not an issue here, you can still import it from /lib/types instead of /types/types

Comment: Thanks. Admittedly struggling to get my head round this, as I don't know really what you mean by 'exporting useful types from package entry point' or 'infer them from public types'; will need to try to research those later. But in any case, importing it from /lib/types has got my app building again for now, so thanks again. I was surprised that the import was in both folders and will need to research that later too.

Comment: I mean it normally should have been `import { type GetReleaseResponse } from '@lionralfs/discogs-client'`, it's the dev's fault that a useful type is not easily available for a consumer

Comment: Got you. Cheers for the help.